# Using Jena to parse json-ld file , I am not seeing the rdfs:container information coming through

Tags: containers, jena, json-ld

I have a jsonld file that I am parsing using Jena. The file has @type @id "rdfs:label" and "rdfs:comment" and also ranges and domains. I have code like this

Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

```
    Reader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    Model model = m.read(fileReader, null, "JSON-LD");
    StmtIterator it = model.listStatements();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    System.out.println("Labels");
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Statement statement = it.next();
```

....
It seems to pick up all the content but does not see the @type statements with rdfs:container. How do I pick up these statements using this parser?

A fragment of the json-ld is
   {
         "@id": "aaa:bbb",
         "@type": [
            "rdfs:container"
         ],
         "rdfs:label": {
            "@language": "en",
            "@value": "cccc"
         },
         "rdfs:comment": {
            "@language": "en",
            "@value": "dddd."
         },
         "rdfs:member": [
            {
               "@id": "aaaa:eeee"
            },
            {
               "@id": "aaaa:fffff"
            }
         ],

When the type is rdfs:class - I get a statement coming through with predicate "type" and the object as the RDFClass, but when the type is rdfs:container - as in the above example I do not get a statement through. I was expecting a statement to come through with the predicate of "type" and a subject with localName of bbb and an object specifying the container class. I do not see such a statement. How to I detect in the parser that the presence of the rdfs:container?

I notice Jena has the concept of Container : https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Container.html.

Comment: Have you tried the JSON-LD at https://json-ld.org/playground/ ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I put it in there. The type comes through, I can put ``` "@type": [
            "rdfs:container"
         ],``` and also ``` "@type": [
            "rdfs:abc"
         ],  ``` I think Jena must be looking for the values it supports (like rdfs:class and ignoring the content it does not understand).

Comment: Jena uses jsonld-java to read in triples. For any formats, Jena does not automatically find containers. App has to use "Resource.as()" etc to say "please treat this as a higher level construction. If you are not seeing different triples from jsonld-java and the JSON playground, then best report it. We here can't tell if the JSON-LD is the right shape. Containers (or rather rdf:Bad/rdf:Alt/rdf:Seq) have properties like "rdf:_1" in them.  rdfs:Container class is a super-class - app needs to say which it is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the object was coming though as a string or http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#container. So I can find it.